# how to hide a particular div tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to write a jQuery code that hides a particular div tag? if so what would this look like? I have a jQuery lightbox and it has a watermark the div that contains the watermark is:

```
<div id="html5-watermark" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;">
    <a href="http://html5box.com/" style="text-decoration:none;" title="jQuery Lightbox">
        <div style="display:block;width:170px;height:20px;text-align:center;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;background-color:#fff;color:#333;font:12px Arial,sans-serif;">
        <div style="line-height:20px;">HTML5 Lightbox Free Version</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Its sourced from html5 and really easy to install unfortunately the code & CSS is hosted somewhere else so I can't edit it directly.

Comment: $('#html5-watermark').hide()?

Comment: where do i post this @AswinRamakrishnan?

Comment: Is 'html5-watermark' the div you are trying to hide?

Comment: that's correct @AswinRamakrishnan

Comment: I think the watermarks is part of the free version, the licensed version has a option to remove it, so check the license to see whether it is permissible to remove it

Comment: try to post the live link, so that we can have a look at it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#html5-watermark').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Add this below your div tag.

Also, I'd recommend reading up on jQuery. It's pretty sweet and useful actually.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Write your own style to overwrite the original style.

`#html5-watermark {
    display:none !important;
 }`

2. There are two methods in jQuery,

`$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#html5-watermark').hide();
    });`

or

`$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#html5-watermark').addClass( 'hideThis' );
    });`

Dont forget to create this css class

`.hideThis {
display:none !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

give a try to include the below code inside your `<head></head>` tag... hope this helps..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#html5-watermark').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find and remove this as well in `html5lightbox.js`:

```
div style='display:block;width:170px;height:20px;text-align:center;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;background-color:#fff;color:#333;font:12px Arial,sans-serif;'><div style='line-height:20px;'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not fair, as author of this script provide two versions of them(free and commercial with branding free). But.. anyway, for simple hide link to author site, change parameter "stamp" from true to false in file html5lightbox.js

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13367424)

Comment: No! This is most simple way to hide unwanted div for asker. Moreover, with this way(which I suggest), still remaine possibility to use SELF watermark, for self branding the lightbox.
Before you raise the reputation and draw conclusions, it is better to hearken to the subject matter.
Sorry for my english )))

Comment: What do you mean with *"This is not fear*"? Do you mean *free*?

Comment: Sorry... I was mean "not fair"(edit my post), because asker want to hide div, in which displayed a watermark of free version of lightbox script.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the style in your view/html.

```
<style>
    #html5-watermark {
       display:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `html5gallery` folder and find out `html5gallery.js`. Edit line number 76 and edit line `display:none !important`

[image]